# How to resize drawing area dynamically via Java?

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage

I'm trying to resize my ***BufferedImage*** (my drawing area) without losing drawn figures on image and resume to draw after resizing.(Like in **Paint.NET**) I'm doing this with JSplitPane from edges and it's happening but when I want to resume to draw, the cursor (the pen) has been about 3 cm away from the drawn figure(shape) because the figures grow with image. It just gets better when I remove the whole picture. [image: Before] **and** [image: After]

I looked at the answers in Google and StackoverFlow, but it did not work with me.How can I get rid of this issue?

I tried like this so far:

**Class UI**

`jSplitPane.addPropertyChangeListener(JSplitPane.DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY, (PropertyChangeEvent evt) -> {
            double imageHeight = jSplitPane.getDividerLocation();
            double imageWidth = imageHeight * 1.6;
            top.setDividerLocation((int) imageWidth);
            drawGround.changeImageSizeDynmcally((int) imageWidth, (int) imageHeight);
            drawGround.repaint();
        });`

**Class DrawGround**

```
     BufferedImage masterImage = new BufferedImage(AREA_WIDTH, AREA_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    //image is master image drawing at first time.

    public void changeImageSizeDynmcally(int w, int h) {
      AREA_WIDTH = w;
      AREA_HEIGHT = h;
      repaint();

      BufferedImage scaledImage = new BufferedImage(AREA_WIDTH, AREA_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g2D = scaledImage.createGraphics();
      g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
      g2D.drawImage(masterImage, 0, 0, null);
      g2D.dispose();
}
```

After this method I have

```
     `@Override
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
        if (masterImage != null) {
            g2D = (Graphics2D) masterImage.getGraphics();
            g2D.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src); 
            bla,bla,bla`
```

Comment: Make a new `BufferedImage` of the size you want, paint the original `BufferedImage` to it (ie `Graphics#drawImage`), assign the new `BufferedImage` to point to the old one...

Comment: You never assign `scaledImage` to anything, so the `masterImage` (which is now the old one) is still been used

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for answer, you are right, now i will try and inform u.

Comment: @MadProgrammer for changing the master image with new scaled image i need to create new method returning BufferedImage.Because In my method it's directly drawing.

Comment: Why not just assign `scaledImage` to `masterImage` within the method (and trigger a repaint) ... `masterImage = scaledImage;`

Comment: @MadProgrammer +1 for you.its a good idea now I'm thinking about this how can assign the scaled image to master but I can't because the scaled image is been drawing area it's not return BufferedImage.If I can change the method it will be

Comment: @MadProgrammer THANK YOU SO MUCH i solved it like this look at to my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132864/discussion-between-coder-acjhp-and-madprogrammer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with creating new method to set the image :

```
public void changeImageSizeDynmcally(int x, int y) {

    AREA_WIDTH = x;
    AREA_HEIGHT = y;
    repaint();

    scaledImage = new BufferedImage(AREA_WIDTH, AREA_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2D = scaledImage.createGraphics();
    g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2D.drawImage(image,0,0, null);

    g2D.dispose();
    setImage(scaledImage); //this is a new method!
}`
```

**The new method is :**

`public void setImage(BufferedImage img) {
        if (img != null) {
            g2D = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
            g2D.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
            g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
            g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB);
            masterImage = img;
            repaint();
        }
    }`
It's working like assigning the new image to old image.

Comment: In `g2D.drawImage(image,0,0, null)`, where is 'image' defined??? Don't you test your code before posting it??? This is a downvotable answer, but I don't use to downvote. I prefer showing people's mistakes!